# How compute the offset of struct

Tags: c++, c

I found a method of computing the offset of struct. as follow:

```
#define offsetOf(type , f)  ((int)\
 ((char *)&((struct tagName*)0)->f-(char*)(struct tagName*)0));
```

but I often write it like this:

```
#define offsetOf(type , f)  ((int)(&((struct tagName*)0)->f);
```

The book said the subtraction of NULL pointer is to make sure it's correct when the inner of NULL pointer is non-zero. but i think that the inner of the NULL pointer is not effect the address of the NULL Pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard library should supply an `offsetof` that does exactly what you want, I would strongly recommend that you use it, as many compilers would issue a warning for the kind of code that would be required for a custom variant.

Anyway, the subtract will take your code from the pointer domain to the domain of `size_t`. I would say that it's a little bit safer.

Comment: thanks ,the size_t is more safe, but i just want to make clear the subtraction of NULL pointer , said in the book " 495 question of c language"

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use the standard offsetof() macro defined in stddef.h?

Comment: thanks, but I just want to make clear of subtraction of NULL pointer,did this work more safe

Comment: @Samuel, using the standard macro would make it clear. It's another thing if you would like to know how it is implemented and how it works. Whether your problem was to compute the offset, or to understand a particular implementation of offsetof() was not clear from your question.

Comment: Excuse me for my pool English . Actually  my question is about the implementation. thanks again.

Comment: Hi Kak, I have found out the standard offsetof() macro which you said , it didn't do the  the subtraction of NULL pointer.but the book"495 questions of C language" said do  the subtraction of NULL pointer will more safe. was it right?

Answer (score 1):

`int` should never be used to save a memory address, use `uintptr_t`. Or just use `offsetof` instead of your own macro.

`0` will never be defined as something other than 0, substracting (char*)0 is just wrong. What book was it that suggested this? Of course the addresses you deal with are just virtual addresses but your program will never see the real addresses.

The statement might make sense on some very obscure system where `NULL` is not 0, and you replace 0 with `NULL` in the macro. Of course, if this system exists it is easy to understand why it's not known and probably a big fail.